# Excel count days per month between two dates using both months and years

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I would like to know how to calculate days of each month between two dates:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | From | To | 01/12/20 | 01/01/21 | 01/02/21 | 01/03/21 | 01/04/21 |
| :-- | :---------: | :-----: | :---------: | :--------: | :--------: | :--------: | :-------: |
| 2 | 15/12/20 | 12/3/21 | 17 | 31 | 28 | 12 | 0 |

I have tried using a formula I found elsewhere on this website but it only picks up the relevant months from the column headers in row 1.  I need it to pick up the years as well.  I wonder if anyone is able to alter this formula to include years as well:

=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(ROW(INDIRECT($A2 & ":" & IF($B2="",TODAY(),$B2))))=MONTH(C1)))

Note: Row 1 Dates are dates and not text.

Charles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
C2: =MAX(MIN(EOMONTH(C$1,0),$B2)-MAX(C$1,$A2)+1,0)
```

and fill across (and down) as needed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ron.  That is perfect.